# React Stripe Elements: The above error occurred in the <CardNumberElement> component

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I am seeing the following error with Stripe React Elements on development:

```
The above error occurred in the <CardNumberElement> component
```

However, there is no error above this error. Further down in the log there is another error:

```
Error: Invalid value for create(): error should be an object. You specified: false. v3:1:10307
t
https://js.stripe.com/v3/:1:10307
lt
https://js.stripe.com/v3/:1:18340
pt
https://js.stripe.com/v3/:1:18411
di/this.create<
https://js.stripe.com/v3/:1:84413
Zt/<
https://js.stripe.com/v3/:1:23612
componentDidMount/<
Element.js:78
addElementsLoadListener
Elements.js:94
componentDidMount
Element.js:77
commitLifeCycles
react-dom.development.js:16227
commitAllLifeCycles
react-dom.development.js:17592
callCallback
react-dom.development.js:149
invokeGuardedCallbackDev
react-dom.development.js:199
invokeGuardedCallback
react-dom.development.js:256
commitRoot
react-dom.development.js:17788
completeRoot
react-dom.development.js:19240
performWorkOnRoot
react-dom.development.js:19169
performWork
react-dom.development.js:19077
performSyncWork
react-dom.development.js:19051
requestWork
react-dom.development.js:18920
scheduleWork
react-dom.development.js:18729
enqueueSetState
react-dom.development.js:12457
./node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js/Component.prototype.setState
react.development.js:375
PersistGate/_this.handlePersistorState
react.js:43
dispatch
redux.js:214
rehydrate
persistStore.js:59
_rehydrate
persistReducer.js:54
persistReducer/</</<
persistReducer.js:79
```

The log also shows the following error:

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”). controller-0438a1e65db60cdbd3d588a9f0c6d344.html:1:1
```

However, I can't see any failed Stripe requests in the network tab.

I only see this error in development (localhost), Stripe loads fine on our QA server. I also generated the QA build and ran it locally and there the error also appears.

Comment: Is it possible that you have two different CSPs?  Maybe one CSP is more strict than the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference, the problem was that I had a wrapping React component for all form fields that was setting a property on its child. Due to the strict CSP from Stripe this is not possible for the Stripe Elements React components.